# DateTime format in c# .Net

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I have a json, I parse the json and get a value in a var created_on like this:

```
var created_on = jsonr["created_at"];
```

The value is

```
created_on = Tue Feb 04 14:02:45 +0000 2014
```

i want to convert it to utc.

I followed quick links in stack but am not able to format accordingly.

Anyone who knows this?

Comment: This looks like UTC date, what do you mean by converting it to UTC ? do you want to display it in a different format ?

Comment: I mean in unix or seconds

Comment: What do you mean by "in a `var` date"? I suspect that's just a string, but we can't tell because you're using `var`. It would be much better if you could convert it to a `DateTime` - and `DateTime` values don't *have* formats as such; they can be formatted in different formats.

Comment: I am unable to convert it to date time. It is showing error

Comment: Why do people feel the need to use `var`'s for everything? It really gets on my nerves.

Comment: @FurquanKhan what is the error?

Comment: @user-12506 For many people it is due to using helper add-ins that enforce a programming standard (e.g. Resharper).

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert jsonvalue to datetime

Comment: I just need to format that and convert it to date time format thats it\

Comment: @FurquanKhan this isn't the right solution, but if the format will always be like this, consider parsing it yourself and building it into a suitable format so that it can be converted to `DateTime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ParseExact` to parse the string into a date:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(created_on,
                    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zz00 yyyy",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        .ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: It is showing an error that the method had some invalid arguments

Comment: Is `created_on` a string?

Comment: var created_on = jsonr["created_at"]; It is a jsonvalue

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything.  Change `var` to `string`

Comment: That will work, but only because JsonValue has an implicit cast to string.